# Proving that set theory Hall's thm and graph theory Hall's thm are equivalent.

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory

What would be the correct method in order to prove that set theory Hall's thm and graph theory Hall's thm are equivalent?

Set theory Hall's thm: 
Let S be a (possibly infinite) family of finite subsets of X, where the members of S are counted with multiplicity. (That is, S may contain the same set several times.)
A transversal for S is the image of an injective function f from S to X such that f(s) is an element of the set s for every s in the family S. In other words, f selects one representative from each set in S in such a way that no two sets from S get the same representative. An alternative term for transversal is system of distinct representatives.

Graph theory Hall's thm:
Let G be a finite bipartite graph with bipartite sets X and Y (i.e. G := (X + Y, E)). An X-saturating matching is a matching which covers every vertex in X.
For a subset W of X, let NG(W) denote the neighborhood of W in G, i.e. the set of all vertices in Y adjacent to some element of W. The marriage theorem in this formulation states that there is an X-saturating matching if and only if for every subset W of X: |W|<=|NG(W)|.

Comment: What is the graph theory Hall's theorem?

Comment: editing my question.

Comment: I've edited my question with more details but I'm only looking for a rigorous method to prove the equivalence, so I would be able to use the graph theory Hall's thm, to solve the set theory problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the infinite case in the set-theoretic version is equivalent to the graph-theoretic version you give, since you only admit finite graphs.

Aside from that, you can make a graph from the set-theoretic version by making one set of vertices $V_1$, the sets in the family (with multiplicity), and the other set $V_2$ the elements of $X$.  $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$ are adjacent iff $v_1\in v_2$.  So, if the graph theory version is true, so is the set theory version.

Given the graph theory version, $X$ is the same in the set theory version, and the sets in $S$ are simply the sets $$S_x=\{y\in Y| xy \in E\},\ x\in X$$  so if the set-theoretic version is true, so is the graph-theoetic version.